# Why doesn't this task execute?

Tags: sass, gulp

Here's my `gulpfile.js`:

```
var gulp = //code code code

var path = {

    // code code code

    watch: {
        styles: './assets/styles/**/*.scss',
        html: './assets/*.html',
        img: './assets/img/**/*.*',
        scripts: './assets/scripts/**/*.js'
    },

    // code code code
};

gulp.task('connect', function() {
    connect.server({
        root: 'public',
        livereload: true
    });
});

gulp.task('styles', function() {
    return gulp.src(path.src.styles)
    .pipe(sass({
        includePaths: [path.bower.foundation.scss, path.bower.awesome.scss]
    }))
    .pipe(autoprefixer({
        browsers: ['last 2 versions', 'safari 5', 'ie 8', 'ie 9']
    }))
    .pipe(concat('app.min.css'))
    .pipe(minifyCss())
    .pipe(gulp.dest(path.public.styles))
    .pipe(connect.reload());
});

gulp.task('header', function() {
    return gulp.src(path.src.header)
    .pipe(sass({
        includePaths: [path.bower.foundation.scss, path.bower.awesome.scss]
    }))
    .pipe(autoprefixer({
        browsers: ['last 2 versions', 'safari 5', 'ie 8', 'ie 9']
    }))
    .pipe(concat('header.min.css'))
    .pipe(minifyCss())
    .pipe(gulp.dest(path.public.styles))
    .pipe(connect.reload());
});

gulp.task('watch', function() {
    gulp.watch(path.watch.html, ['html']);
    gulp.watch(path.watch.styles, ['styles']);
    gulp.watch(path.watch.scripts, ['scripts']);
    gulp.watch(path.watch.img, ['img']);
});

gulp.task('header', ['connect', 'html', 'fonts', 'header', 'watch']);
gulp.task('default', ['connect', 'html', 'fonts', 'styles', 'scripts', 'img', 'watch']);
```

When I run 'gulp header' I get this:

```
D:\Dropbox\foundation-project>gulp header
[11:23:34] Using gulpfile D:\Dropbox\foundation-project\gulpfile.js
```

And nothing else happens with my `header.scss`.
When I run gulp it works fine.

Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Solved by changing the name of the task. It didn't work because I had 2 tasks called "header"